# How to exclude documents using has_child filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I have following mapping in my elasticsearch:

`my_parent` - Parent type

`my_child` - Child type (has many-to-one relation with `my_parent`)

Suppose `my_child` has field `name`.

What I want to do is to get all `my_parent` documents that does not have any children documents with `name` equals to `test`.

Here is an equivalent in SQL:

`SELECT * FROM my_parent WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT parent_id
    FROM my_child
    WHERE name = 'test'
)`

Can this be done in elasticsearch in a single query? Or I should use 2 queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `has_child` and `bool` `must_not` queries to achieve what you want.

```
POST <indexname>/my_parent/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must_not": [
            {
               "has_child": {
                  "type": "my_child",
                  "query": {
                     "term": {
                        "name": {
                           "value": "test"
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but its not what I want. This query works like this: get all parent documents that have at least one child which value of ``name`` field is not ``test``. But I want following: exclude all parent documents that have at least one child which value of ``name`` field is ``test``. What I mean: suppose I have parent document with 2 child documents, which ``name`` field values are ``test`` and ``not test`` correspondingly. I don't want this document because it has child which value of ``name`` field is ``test``.

Comment: Got it. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/has-child.html

You can look into the above link, there they have mentioned how to get parent based on child...

You take that query and put it inside a must_not clause of a bool filter/query..

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/combining-filters.html#bool-filter?q=bool filter

Here is the link on how to use bool filter..

Let me know if you need a more deeper explaination